# Intuit IPP nuking jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10, intuit-partner-platform

I'm integrating an application with the Intuit IPP program. This requires loading their JS from `https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js`. This works in every browser expected for IE10 (EDIT: also broken in IE9). This failure happens on Win7 & Win8.

The nature of the problem is that it's removing jQuery. Everything works up until the file is included and all calls to both `$` and `jQuery` fail immediately afterwards. When I say it's removed: `$(document)` raises "Object Expected" and `jQuery === undefined` returns true.

Again, I want to emphasis that this problem is only happening in IE10. Has anybody else experienced this problem? Any tips?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Turns out I was incorrect when I originally opened the ticket. IE9 is experiencing the same problem.

**EDIT #2**: I set up this jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/3jwRp/2/. Runs fine in chrome but raises the alert in IE

Comment: I've tried loading the intuit anywhere file both before and after jquery.js with no impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by a known error with the Intuit script discussed at [Intuit Anywhere script reloading jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791357/intuit-anywhere-script-reloading-jquery/17791550) (Intuit Ticket number - IPP-1811)

Chrome & FF handled reloading jQuery more gracefully than IE so it was a more obvious problem, but the underlying cause was on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the solution on our developer site for IE8 and above:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/widgets/0010_connect_button

Specifically: 
To display the Connect to QuickBooks button in IE8, the html xmlns attribute is required, for example:

If this too does not resolve your issue, then please raise a support ticket at:
https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Also, just wanted to understand if you are also using some other jquery in your project? Then follow the 2 steps:
Can you use the solutions mentioned in the below link:

1)Reference the jquery 1.0 library at the topmost position and used a CDN location to refer it. Add the CDN site to your trusted site list

2) Check if there is no extra comma or > in your script by mistake. Other browsers can resolve this but not ie.

Refer:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUsing_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries%26redirect%3Dno

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-jquery-noconflict-lightbox-and-jquery-conflict

Comment: I'll send in a support ticket. The problem is quite apparent in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jwRp/

Comment: We aren't able to use the jQuery CDN, but instead load a copy off our servers. I did just notice that the intuit script is adding a second jquery load to our head. This is probably causing some naming collisions. How do we prevent the intuit script from re-requiring jQuery? Shouldn't it see that jQuery is already loaded on the page and not reload it?

Comment: Can you please clarify which Jquery you are loading from your servers?

Comment: `1.10.2` someone explained that the script is broken so that it thinks that `1.10.2 < 1.4.2`. Explained in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791357/intuit-anywhere-script-reloading-jquery/17791550?noredirect=1#17791550

Comment: Yes.I added another solution link too for your issue on the above page.