# Intuit Anywhere script reloading jQuery

Tags: jquery, intuit-partner-platform

Our application loads jQuery 1.10.2 and then loads `https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js` from Intuit. The anywhere script is adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the head and reloading jQuery.

This is wiping the namespace and wrecking much of our code. Shouldn't the script see that jQuery is already loaded? How do we prevent jquery from being reloaded?

Thanks,
Forrest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT:

The problem seems to be that `window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2"` returns false as `'1.10.2' < '1.4.2'` will also return false. It is because javascript will see it as `1.1.2 < 1.4.2`. Another option is to remove the `|| window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2"`

---

If you are sure that you are including jQuery just change the part of the code where it appends the script tag.

At the bottom of the script. Change

```
// function that starts it all. timeout is 0
(function() {
    // these are the domains whose js files we're going to look at
    // intuit.ipp.ourDomain = /(.intuit.com).*?#(.*)/;
    intuit.ipp.ourDomain = /intuit.com$/;
    if(window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2") {
        // minimum version 1.4.2
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js");
        script_tag.onload = function () {
            if(window.jQuery) {
                intuit.ipp.jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
                intuit.ipp.anywhere.windowLoad();
            }
        };
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // Same thing but for IE
            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                script_tag.onload();
            }
        };

        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

    } else {
        // we do have jquery
        intuit.ipp.jQuery = window.jQuery;
        intuit.ipp.anywhere.windowLoad();
    }
})();
```

To

```
// function that starts it all. timeout is 0
(function () {
    // these are the domains whose js files we're going to look at
    // intuit.ipp.ourDomain = /(.intuit.com).*?#(.*)/;
    intuit.ipp.ourDomain = /intuit.com$/;
    // we do have jquery
    intuit.ipp.jQuery = window.jQuery;
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.windowLoad();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Spokey is partially correct.

In order to serve the Anywhere script locally, you also need to make some modifications to the code for allowing the domain to point to the Intuit site. This way, the CSS and the Application links on the Blue Dot Menu are redirected correctly to Intuit's domain.

(Note: Updating the `intuit.ipp.ourDomain` variable won't work as stated above.)

Here is what I modified:

Lines 20-40 contains:

```
windowLoad  : function() {
    intuit.ipp.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        intuit.ipp.jQuery('script').each(function (){
            // check if this script file is from our domain
            if (!this.src) {
                return;
            }
            var jsSrc = this.src;
            var jsSrcParts = jsSrc.replace(/http[s]?:\/\//, '').split('/');
            var qs = intuit.ipp.ourDomain.exec(jsSrcParts[0]);
            if(!qs) {
                qs = document.domain.match(intuit.ipp.ourDomain);
            }
            if (!qs || !jsSrcParts[jsSrcParts.length - 1].match('intuit.ipp.anywhere') || !jsSrc.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)) {
                return;
            }
            // get ipp's domain
            intuit.ipp.anywhere.serviceHost = jsSrc.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
```

I replaced with these:

```
windowLoad  : function() {
    intuit.ipp.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        intuit.ipp.jQuery('script').each(function (){
            // check if this script file is from our domain
            if (!this.src) {
                return;
            }
            var jsSrc = this.src;
            var jsSrcParts = jsSrc.replace(/http[s]?:\/\//, '').split('/');
            var qs = intuit.ipp.ourDomain.exec(jsSrcParts[0]);
            // if(!qs) {
            //  qs = document.domain.match(intuit.ipp.ourDomain);
            // }
            if (!jsSrcParts[jsSrcParts.length - 1].match('intuit.ipp.anywhere') || !jsSrc.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)) {
                return;
            }
            // get ipp's domain
            //intuit.ipp.anywhere.serviceHost = jsSrc.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
            intuit.ipp.anywhere.serviceHost = "appcenter.intuit.com";
```