# jquery version conflit with intuit.ipp.anywhere.js

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are using jquery 1.10.1. we always load 1.10.1 before running intuit.ipp.anywhere.js. The issue we face is that both Jquery 1.6 and 1.10.1(ours) are loaded. despite  the fact that there is a checking in  intuit.ipp.anywhere.js. after investigating we noticed that the condition **window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2"** is not properly executed. e.g: with JQuery 1.7 we didn't face any issue. It seems that the statement is executed as string compare. Below is the concerned code in intuit.ipp.anywhere.js

```
if(window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2") {
    // minimum version 1.4.2
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js");
    script_tag.onload = function () {
        if(window.jQuery) {
            intuit.ipp.jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
            intuit.ipp.anywhere.windowLoad();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug for IE has already been resolved in our previous release.
Please take the latest jquery lib - https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js (if you are loading it locally)
You can also refer-[Intuit IPP nuking jQuery in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752294/intuit-ipp-nuking-jquery-in-ie/17775341#comment25953248_17775341)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using the latest  intuit.ipp.anywhere.js from appcenter.intuit.com. You can find this statement 'window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2"'. I think the issue is from this statement **"1.10.1" < "1.4.2"** which return true and that's why jquery 1.6 is loaded despite the fact that 1.10.1 is already loaded.

Comment: I would suggest you to try the workaround which I have mentioned above then and raise a support ticket with details here for this issue -https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll raise a support tichet from that.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? We support IE9 and IE10 only. Also did you use the following tag in your page      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">